# How to call the assigned smarty variable

Tags: php, smarty

Good evening,

I am using a smarty cms and I am trying to display the "proucts_quantity" but it does not work. I have already tried all possible and used cases which are already present in the template but it will not show.
The variable "products_quantity" is an assigned variable and visibly through {debug}

--> Template

```
   <!--             
  {if $products_item_array.shipping_time}
        <br />{$info.text_shipping_time}: {$products_item_array.shipping_time}
   {/if}
   -->
    <br />{$info.text_shipping_time}: {$products_item_array.products_quantity}
```

--> Debug
http://www.pic-upload.de/view-25300549/Untitled2.jpg.html

The Variable "products_quantity" is not present in the php file so I assume that it is included in some array. Unfortunately the file is to long to post it here and I am not sure whish sniped is important.
http://www.file-upload.net/download-9867993/checkout_confirmation.zip.html

I would appreciate if anyone could help me out, how to call the variable or how to find it out.

Comment: I had to use {$products_item_array.DATA_ARRAY.products_quantity} bold letters in > DATA_ARRAY <  -.-  thanks for the help

Answer (score 0):

Data which You are looging is in $content_data variable.

So to display 'quantity', try

```
 {foreach from=$content_data.products_data item=product}
      {$product.quantity}
 {/foreach}
```

($content_data.products_data is an array)

Good way to debuging in smarty is using var_dump like:

```
 <pre>{$content_data|@var_dump}</pre>
```

Comment: I want to use the variable products_quantity. The variable quantity is somehow eather 1 or 0 and I have no Idea why they have done it like this.  I´ll try to debug like you told me